# Add PREV and NEXT to an HTML5 Page That's Using IFrame

Tags: html

I have an HTML5 webpage with an iframe in the center of it.
Different pages load within the iframe when the numbered links are clicked.
These numbered links are on the initial HTML5 page (below the iframe tag).
I'd like to have a working PREV and NEXT link beside the numbered links but don't know how to do it.

This is what I have so far:

```
<div>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li class="prev"><a href="#">&laquo; Previous</a></li>
      <li><a href="news-pg1.html" target="iframe_a">1</a></li>
      <li><a href="news-pg2.html" target="iframe_a">2</a></li>
      <li><a href="news-pg3.html" target="iframe_a">3</a></li>
      <li><a href="news-pg4.html" target="iframe_a">4</a></li>
      <li><a href="news-pg5.html" target="iframe_a">5</a></li>
      <li><a href="news-pg6.html" target="iframe_a">6</a></li>
      <li><a href="news-pg7.html" target="iframe_a">7</a></li>
      <li class="next"><a href="#">Next &raquo;</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
```

So the issue I have is that I don't know how to tell the PREV link to load the previous IFRAME and the same for the NEXT link.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

solved this using the Javascript function incrementId() already found to exist else where  in stackoverflow itself. I cloned this and slightly tweaked to decrementId. These functions take a parameter (like this: "news-pg1") and increments to news-pg2 to which ".html" can be appended and so on and then loads the iframe with the html content. 
added an click event handler to list tag.Added two functions SetPrev and SetNext to handle frame loads

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
var f='news-pg1'; 

function newContent()     {
document.getElementById('fr_content').src =f+ ".html";
}
 function decrementId(id)     {
  // regexp is looking for text with a number suffix.  adjust accordingly.
  var numberSuffixRegExp = /(.*?)(\d*)$/;
  var regExpMatch = numberSuffixRegExp.exec(id);
  // assuming a match will be made here, and position 1 and 2 are populated.
  var prefix = regExpMatch[1];
  var counter = parseInt(regExpMatch[2]);
      if (counter > 1)
         counter--;
  return prefix + counter;
}

 function incrementId(id)     {
  // regexp is looking for text with a number suffix.  adjust accordingly.
  var numberSuffixRegExp = /(.*?)(\d*)$/;
  var regExpMatch = numberSuffixRegExp.exec(id);
  // assuming a match will be made here, and position 1 and 2 are populated.
  var prefix = regExpMatch[1];
  var counter = parseInt(regExpMatch[2]);
   if (counter     < 3)     {
       counter++;
}
  return prefix + counter;
}
function setNext()     {
try     {
f=incrementId(f);
document.getElementById('fr_content').src=f+".html";    
} catch(e)     {
ErrorHandler.handleError(e);
}
} //setNext
function setPrev()     {
f=decrementId(f);
document.getElementById('fr_content').src=f+".html";    
}
</script>
<head>
<body>
<div>
  <nav>
        <iframe id="fr_content" src="news-pg1.html" width=300 height=200>
        </iframe>
    <ul style=list-style-type: inline;>
      <li  onclick="setPrev();">    <u>Prev    </u>    </li>  
      <li  onclick="setNext();">    <u>Next    </u>    </li>  
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```